# how can I fix my error from where in at the moment when I try to insert to my table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to to once the user has sold an item, but if my final stock if less than my min stock then it will insert a notification on my table from database, but after that push with node.js that notification, but when I try to insert to my table after sale show me an error like this how should I fix it?

```
public function concretar_venta(){
            if($this->sale->checa_carrito_vacio($this->session->carrito)){
                $total = $this->input->post("total", TRUE);
                $cantidad_pagada = $this->input->post("cantidad_pagada", TRUE);
                $cambio = $cantidad_pagada - $total;
                if($this->sale->concretar_venta($this->session->carrito, $total, $cantidad_pagada, $cambio)){
                    $this->json(array('success' => 'The sale was successfully made'));
                }
                else{
                    $this->json(array('error' => 'There was an error making the sale, please try again'));
                }

                $this->session->carrito = $this->sale->checar_existe_carrito();
                $array = $this->sale->get_all_cart($this->session->carrito);
                $product_id = array();
                foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                    $product_id[] = $value['id'];
                }

                $this->notification->addNotification('low stock', $product_id, $this->session->log['id'], 'low stock');

                /*if ($product->stock <= 8) {
                    $this->notification->addNotification('low stock', $product_id, $this->session->log['id'], 'low stock');
                } else {
                    # code...
                }*/

            }
            else{
                $this->json(array('error' => 'The cart is empty'));
            }
        }
```

model notification:

```
public function addNotification($message, $product_id, $user_id, $type = ''){
        $types = array('new' => 0, 'pending' => 1, 'low stock' => 2);
        if (isset($types[$type]) === false) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
        }
        $type = $types[$type];
        $timestamp = time();
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id IN ? AND type = ? ";
        $previousNotification = $this->db->query($query, array($product_id, $type))->result_array();
        if ($previousNotification[0]['notificationCount'] == 0) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            try {
                foreach ($product_id as $pid) {
                    if (!$this->db->query($sql, array($message, $type, $pid, $user_id, $timestamp))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

error output:

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND type = 2' at line 1 SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id IN () AND type = 2 Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/storelte/system/database/DB_driver.php Line Number: 691

Comment: `IN()` requires arguments

Comment: ou should backtick your column names

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass an array `$product_id` into a single parameter. That won't work. You'll have to do some manipulation to get it to check for every product_id in that array.

Comment: yeah , it should be my pid from model , and argument it is $product_id[] = $value['id']; from controller , i dont know where the error come from

Answer (score 0):

`IN()` requires a string of product_ids to check in, so you need to convert your array of product_ids to a string

between these lines:

```
 $timestamp = time();
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*)...
```

add

```
 $timestamp = time();
 $product_id = implode(',',$product_id);//add this line
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*)...
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php